# How to get pip3 without sudo privileges

Tags: software-installation, pip

I need to install `pip3`, but cannot do it without sudo privileges which I don't have.
I have tried `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` but that gets me the other version of pip.

Comment: What python version? Versions newer than 3.4 already have `pip` bundled, just run `python -m pip <command>`. In that case, you don't need to install `pip` via `get-pip.py` script as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can install `pip3` without root previlege as follow:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --user
```

`pip3` will be installed locally under `/home/$USER/.local/bin/`.

Check the installed version:

```
$HOME/.local/bin/pip3 -V
```

or

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
pip3 --version
```

sample output:

```
pip 10.0.1 from /home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: Isntall typo first line

Comment: I installed pip like this, and right now I have to remove it right now. How can I do that ? It is located in `HOME/.local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

If you need pip3 to install packages for python3, you can use pip to install packages for specific versions of python. You could try:

```
python3.6 get-pip.py
```

and then:

```
python3.6 -m pip install <package>
```

replacing for your version of python and the package.