# Why does "get-pip.py" complain about invalid syntax?

Tags: python, python3, pip

I am trying to install `pip3` without having sudo privileges following the answer provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445906/how-to-get-pip3-without-sudo-privileges). The first step is to execute the following:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

It seems to work without problems. However, when I execute the second step:

```
python3 get-pip.py --user
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24226, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 896, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1139, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1115, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1096, in _legacy_get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 444, in spec_from_loader
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 533, in spec_from_file_location
  File "/tmp/tmphdj_zdji/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought that the problem was that I did not specify my user-name after `--user`. However, it does not help. I still get the same error.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

**ADDED:**

As it was suggested in comments, the problem might be caused by the fact that `get-pip.py` works only for python 3.6 version or higher and I have version 3.5.

To overcome the problem I have tried:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.5/get-pip.py | python3
```

It has been executed without errors. As output I got:

```
Successfully installed pip-20.3.4 setuptools-50.3.2 wheel-0.36.2
```

Comment: The second step is `python3 get-pip.py --user`, not `get-pip.py --user` — which did you run?

Comment: Could you check what version of python you are running.  The syntax error is because it uses a python feature called "f-string" which didn't exist until python 3.6.  So the script will need to be edited or you will need to run with python 3.6 or later

Comment: However as Stephen kKit points out, if you didn't run it with python3 and just ran `get-pip.py --user`, you *might* have accidentally run it with python 2

Comment: I have run "python3 get-pip.py --user". The version of python that I have is "3.5.2". So, it looks like the version is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround for Python 2.7

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

**P.S.** : Is not a workaround, they dropped the support for 2.7 https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/433

Comment: So Python 2.7 is no longer supported, but is also required by CentOS/RedHat 7 (which are supported until 2024). Delightful...